# LinkedList of File IO appears the same through output

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, linked-list

The LinkedList only shows the same output. I am trying to use the last while loop but it does not work. This is a "Duck Duck Goose" problem. I am not supposed to use Indexing.

19 names

http://collabedit.com/q248e

```
public class DuckDuckGoose {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
    // add try catch to add list
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(...players.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            linkedlist.add(inFile.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Iterator<String> iterator = linkedlist.iterator();

    // checks until the last list
    while (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next().equals(getRandomBoolean())) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(linkedlist);
}

public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    return Math.random() < 10 * 0.5;
}
}
```

Comment: See also: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (iterator.next().equals(getRandomBoolean())) {
```

This is never true, because the iterator contains `String`s, not `Boolean`s, so you never execute the `iterator.remove();`.

Instead:

```
iterator.next(); // gets but ignores the next String.
if (getRandomBoolean()) {
```

---

Additionally, your loop never executes:

```
while (!iterator.hasNext()) {
```

because the iterator initially has a next element.

Remove the `!`.

---

Additionally, this:

```
Math.random() < 10 * 0.5
```

Is always true, because `Math.random()` is strictly less than 1, and `10 * 0.5` is 5.

Drop the `10 *`, or pick a value on the RHS of the `<` which is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you! The output is still showing all 19 names. It is not removing until the last winner.

Comment: Thanks again sir. It is showing three or four names left. How else should I fix this?

Comment: @ashkanaral depends entirely upon what you consider to be wrong about there being 3 or 4 remaining values. Please, have a go yourself.